# FParsec Parsing list with optional content, fails on continuing with next parser

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm trying to parse a list of asset types where each asset type potentially has a name. After the list is done I'd like to continue parsing a list of attributes for the asset types, one list for all asset types.

The string I'm trying to parse looks like:
`converter named a023, signaltower, powerunit named 23 attributes power, temperature`
 The parser signature looks like 
`Parser<((Asset * AssetName option) list * Attribute liste),unit>`
I got parsing the assets name, and the attributes separately, the problem arise when I combine the two and list is done, it then fails on the attributes string stating `Expecting: 'named'`.

To me it seems that it is trying the opt assetname parser which fails on the attributes string, but I am not sure how to ignore that and move on when the list is "done" (after all the asset name part is optional)..

```
type AssetName = AssetName of string
let named = str "named" >>. spaces1 >>. word
let assetName = spaces1 >>. (named |>> AssetName)

type Asset = | Converter | Signaltower | Powerunit 
let assetType = ["converter"; "signaltower"; "powerunit";] |> Seq.map pstring |> choice
let findAsset = function
| "converter" -> Converter
| "signaltower" -> Signaltower
| "powerunit" -> Powerunit
| _ -> raise <| Exception "Invalid asset type"
let asset = (assetType |>> findAsset) .>>. opt assetName 

type Attribute = Attribute of string
let attribute = word |>> Attribute
let attributes = spaces1 >>. str "attributes" >>. spaces1 >>. sepBy attribute commaMaybeSpace

let p = sepBy asset (pchar ',' >>. spaces) .>>. attributes
let r input = run p3 input
r "converter named a023, signaltower, powerunit named 23 attributes power, temperature"
```

Comment: Could it be the typo in the string on the last line? It is missing a `c` since it starts with `onverter` instead of `converter`. I have no clue if that helps or not :)

Comment: Just a typo from my copy/paste unfortunatly. Parsing the asset types and names without attributes works as expected.

Comment: then you need help from a proper expert :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** As discussed in a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662400) and also hinted at in the [documentation](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.attempt), an optional parser `opt p` fails if `p` fails after changing its state. Instead, backtracking (restoring the state) should be used, either with the `attempt` parser, or with one of the backtracking operators.

Keeping in mind that `opt (attempt (p >>. q))` is equivalent to `opt (p >>? q)`, try

```
let assetName = spaces1 >>? (named |>> AssetName)
```

---

Not sure if it has some bearing on the issue, but the type of the parser in the example does not match the grammar you are describing. I think you want:

> *asset-type* :
>      | Converter | Signaltower | Powerunit
>
> *named-asset* :
>      | *asset-type* | *asset-type* **named** *ident*
>
> *asset-list* :
>      *named-asset*,...,*named-asset*
>
> *attributed-asset-list* :
>       *asset-list* **attributes** *ident-list*

The following line does not repeat the parser for *named-asset*.

```
let p = asset .>>. attributes
// val p : Parser<((Asset * AssetName option) * Attribute list),unit>
```

You can replace it with

```
let p = sepBy asset (pchar ',' >>. spaces) .>>. attributes
// val p : Parser<((Asset * AssetName option) list * Attribute list),unit>

"converter named a023, signaltower, powerunit named 23 attributes power, temperature"
|> run p |> printfn "%A" 
// Success: ([(Converter, Some (AssetName "a023")); (Signaltower, null);
//   (Powerunit, Some (AssetName "23"))],
//  [Attribute "power"; Attribute "temperature"])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close, but it fails if the last asset is just powerunit.. 
```
"converter named a023, signaltower, powerunit attributes-  power, temperature" |> run p |> printfn "%A" 
//Failure:
//Error in Ln: 1 Col: 46
//converter named a023, signaltower, powerunit attributes power, temperature 
//                                                                          ^
//Expecting: 'named'

val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: @hsulriksen The penny drops. We probably need some [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662400) here, `let assetName = spaces1 >>? (named |>> AssetName)`.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried with >>? and >>.? but at the wrong place (instead of the opt). Now I just need to decode this to some logic in this head of mine.